# PHP: Handling loops and replacement correctly

Tags: php

While programming my game, I ran into an issue when working with our genetics. The long and short of our genetics is that they can be utilized and analyzed in several ways. They are broken into B/b/b1/b2, O/o, W/w, and C/c1/c2 at this time.

The problem with the code occurs at this point when handling the C/c1/c2 portion of a string that is equal to 6. I had to utilize the current code to get it to not add extra C/c1/c2 sequences, however, it runs into an issue where it is not adding them to a genetic code that might be BBooww-- (where -- is C/c1/c2 sequence) and often adds to many to a sequence like bbooww--c2c2 (our Pink Albino sequence).

Below is the foreach and if statements I am using. Any help in shortening or optimizing it would be

```
$coat_genes = str_split($coat_combination);
$full_coat_combination = "";

foreach($coat_genes as $coat_gene)
{ 
    if ($coat_gene != "-")
    {
        $full_coat_combination.= $coat_gene;
        continue;
    } else {

        if (strlen($full_coat_combination) <= 4 && strpos(strtolower($full_coat_combination), "oo") === false)
        {
            $o = "";

            $chance = rand(1, 2);

            $o .= ($chance == 1)  
                ? "O"
                : "o";

            if ($o == "O")
            {
                $chance = rand(1, 2);

                $o .= ($chance == 1) 
                    ? "O"
                    : "o";

            } else {
                $o .= "o";
            }

            $full_coat_combination .= $o;
        }

        if (strlen($full_coat_combination) <= 6 && strpos(strtolower($full_coat_combination) , "ww") === false)
        {
            $w = "";

            $chance = rand(1, 2);

             $w .= ($chance == 1) 
                ? "W"
                : "w";

            if ($w == "W")
            {
                $chance = rand(1, 2);

                $w .= ($chance == 1)
                    ? "W" 
                    : "w";
            } else {
                $w .= "w";
            }

            $full_coat_combination .= $w;
        }

        if (strlen($full_coat_combination) > 6 
        && strpos(strtolower($full_coat_combination) , "cc") === false 
        && strpos(strtolower($full_coat_combination) , "cc1") === false 
        && strpos(strtolower($full_coat_combination) , "cc2") === false 
        && strpos(strtolower($full_coat_combination) , "c1c1") === false 
        && strpos(strtolower($full_coat_combination) , "c1c2") === false 
        && strpos(strtolower($full_coat_combination) , "c2c1") === false 
        && strpos(strtolower($full_coat_combination) , "c2c2") === false)
        {
            $c = "";

            $chance = rand(1, 3);

            if ($chance == 1) 
            {
                $c.= "C";

            } elseif ($c == "c1") {
                $c.= "c1";
            } else {
                $c.= "c2";
            }

            if ($c == "C")
            {
                $chance = rand(1, 3);

                if ($chance == 1) 
                {
                    $c.= "C";
                } elseif ($chance == 2) { 
                    $c.= "c1";
                } else { 
                    $c.= "c2";
                }
            } else {
                $chance = rand(1, 2);

                $c .= ($chance == 1) 
                    ? "c1"
                    : "c2";
            }
            $full_coat_combination.= $c;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Coat combination is pulled from a database. Some samples follow:

Melanistic: BB------ (O/o, W/w, C/c1/c2 respectively)
Strawberry: bbOOww-- (C/c1/c2)
Blue Albino (one of our most problematic sequences): bboo--c1c1 (W/w)
Pink Albino (same as blue): bboo--c2c2

Thanks!

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Provide sample input and expected output please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought this looked like an interesting problem. If I understand your question and code properly:

1. Your database contains genetics which are represented as sequences
   of four pairs. These sequences occur in a consistent pattern, such
   that the first pair consists of two selections from the set [B, b,
   b1, b2], the second pair from the set [O, o], the third pair from
   the set [W, w] and fourth pair from the set [C, c1, c2].
2. Some of the pairs are replaced by pairs of dashes as placeholders.
   Your program must replace the dashes with random elements from the
   appropriate set considering their placement in the main sequence.
   Since your code does not address the first pair (the B group), I
   assume those will always be present.
3. To construct the replacement pairs, you first randomly select one element from
   the appropriate set. The second element is also randomly selected,
   but if the first element is one of the lowercase options, the second
   element may not be uppercase.

First, I would use a regular expression match to separate the sequence into its components rather than using str_split, because some of the elements consist of multiple characters.

```
preg_match_all('/([BbOoWwCc][12]?|-)/', $coat_combination, $coat_genes);
```

When you have the sequence in an array, you may iterate over it as you are currently doing, but instead of checking `$full_coat_combination` repeatedly, you can replace each of the dashes with an element from the appropriate set using a specific rule for each position in the sequence.

```
$full_coat_combination = ''; // container for resulting sequence
$prev = ''; // to handle uppercase/lowercase requirement
$c_options = array('C', 'c1', 'c2');
foreach($coat_genes[0] as $i => $gene) {
    if ($gene == "-") {
        if ($i == 2) {
            // you may use rand(0,1) to generate a random boolean
            $gene = rand(0, 1) ? 'O' : 'o';
        } elseif ($i == 3) {
            $gene = 'o'; // default value is lowercase
            // if previous was uppercase, then randomly select upper or lower
            if ($prev == 'O') $gene = rand(0, 1) ? 'O' : 'o';
        } elseif ($i == 4) { // W uses the same logic as O
            $gene = rand(0, 1) ? 'W' : 'w';
        } elseif ($i == 5) {
            $gene = 'w';
            if ($prev == 'W') $gene = rand(0, 1) ? 'W' : 'w';
        } elseif ($i == 6) {
            // randomly select an element from the three possibilities
            $gene = $c_options[rand(0, 2)];
        } elseif ($i == 7) {
            // if the previous was not uppercase, exclude the index for upper
            $x = $prev == 'C' ? rand(0, 2) : rand(1, 2);
            $gene = $c_options[$x];
        }
    }
    $prev = $gene; // current becomes previous for the next iteration
    $full_coat_combination .= $gene;
}
```

Comment: This looks like a beautifully compact way to do things, but when implementing, I am given a parse error. I'm not quite sure why, though, everything appears just fine from where I'm standing. Any thoughts? Thanks so much!

Comment: It could be the use of the short array syntax if your PHP version is less than 5.4. (`['C', 'c1', 'c2']` instead of `array('C', 'c1', 'c2')`).

Comment: PHP 5.4 is running on my server. How strange. I'll keep tinkering with it and be sure to accept this answer once I figure out what's going on and make sure it's what I think I'm looking for (which I do)!

Comment: @user2321275 Oops, I was still using a PHP 5.5 feature. Referring directly to an array literal (e.g. `array('C', 'c1', 'c2')[1]`) isn't possible yet in 5.4. I updated the answer so it should work with 5.4. I really need to be more careful about that when answering questions.